# What are my options when it comes to saving and reloading data with Quill.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, quill

I am making a note taking app and it is in the early prototyping stages, so I just want to hack together something that will work for myself.
My text editor is built using Quill, and I'm using Vue to structure the whole application. Currently, I don't have a back end, so no server.js.
I would like my application to be able to save the information that I put in the editor, and reload the information whenever I rebuild the app.

I checked out the autosave option provided by Quill [here](https://quilljs.com/playground/#autosave)
But I'm not sure what to do with `$.post` and where to post it.

Can I simply post it to a local .json file?

What is the best thing to save in my case? The example was logging changes, what am I supposed to do with changes?

I apologize beforehand for the lack of clarity in my question, as I don't know exactly what I should be asking to achieve what I want.
Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

So if I understood correctly, what you're asking is how to implement quilljs' auto save feature when you have no server. But, you've already answered your own questions.

- A simple way to do it would be saving the document into a local json file. But I don't know if you can do that using js.
- Another way of doing it, is to save the content to the browser's local storage and loading the data every time you load the app.

  ```
  var Delta = Quill.import('delta');
  var quill = new Quill('#editor-container', {
    modules: {
      toolbar: true
    },
    placeholder: 'Compose an epic...',
    theme: 'snow'
  });

  // Store accumulated changes
  var change = new Delta();
  quill.on('text-change', function(delta) {
    change = change.compose(delta);
  });

  // Save periodically
  setInterval(function() {
    if (change.length() > 0) {
      console.log('Saving changes', change);
      // Save the entire updated text to localStorage
      const data = JSON.stringify(quill.getContents())
      localStorage.setItem('storedText', data);
      change = new Delta();
    }
  }, 5*1000);

  // Check for unsaved data
  window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    if (change.length() > 0) {
      return 'There are unsaved changes. Are you sure you want to leave?';
    }
  }
  ```

Then inside your vue component's `mounted()`, use the following to fetch the saved data:

```
const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('storedText'));
```

Comment: Hey Stormix, im trying to understand your answer (im a noob) What do you mean with the vue components mounted?

Comment: Oh, OP was using Vue js, which has a lifecycle hook called mounted that is executed whenever the page/component are rendered. Think of it as a 'on page load' listener.
If you're not using vue js, then you can ignore that part, and just get the stored info whenever you want using that snippet.